# Сannot load stylesheet after adding in web.config file rules <rewrite>

Tags: html, css, redirect, iis, web-config

Well, I have a simple bootstrap page, with CSS styles and background for the site on IIS, which is available during the upgrade of the main site.

Everything works fine, the page displays styles work until you need to configure properly redirect.

Created a file in the directory with a stub **web.config** and added the code there (the user on the page **web.test.com/something** moved to **web.test.com**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite to root" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After adding the rule, I see a page without styles, only letters and blank background

Add to file **web.config**

```
<location path="images">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
<location path="css">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Nothing change, what do I do wrong?

CSS file

```
body {  
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg)no-repeat 0px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center;

}
h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3C362B;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Mistral', cursive;
}
/*--main--*/
.main {
    padding: 3.5em 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.main-row {
    width: 110%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.main-row p {
    font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva', serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #3C362B;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
}
```

Index . html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Site for upgrade</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->

</head>
<body>
    <!-- main -->
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Site for upgrade..</h1>
                <div class="main-row">
                    <p>We apologize for any inconvenience. Work on the update is underway. The site will be available soon.</p>
                </div>
        </div>  
    <!-- //main -->  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT should reveal more to you on what's wrong with this rewrite rule.

Comment: Do you have any update about this issue? I think Lex Li's suggestion will help u find something.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 check the 404 http request.

> Created a file in the directory with a stub web.config and added the code there (the user on the page web.test.com/something moved to web.test.com:

Obviously because there is a error with the path of your file.

**How to solve it ?**

1. Change the path in your static files, like css file.
2. Workaround: Copy and paste all the static file to the path which you find it by using F12 Network tools, this method is only used to verify whether the issue is due to this reason.

Comment: I don’t get 404 error, through F12 I see only codes 200 and 301, redirect works. Not only styles, page white with text

Comment: @Константин can you check the css file via browser ?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t understand the question. Оpen the file style.css through the browser then of course I can. BUT Found that if i add  <location path="~/images/bg.jpg">  as  <configuration> <location path="~/images/bg.jpg"> <system.webServer> <rewrite>            <rules> <rule name="Rewrite to root" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="." /><action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/srpvpreprod/" /> </rule> </rules> </rewrite> </system.webServer> </location> </configuration> Then the styles work, but the redirection does not work. write404 if enter name.site/something